# Geometry for an odd perfect number? (Second question)

Tags: nt.number-theory, hilbert-spaces, computational-number-theory, perfect-numbers

Let $e_d$ be the $d$-th standard-basis vector in the Hilbert space $H=l_2(\mathbb{R})$.
Let $h(n)  = J_2(n)$ be the second Jordan totient function.
Define:

$$\phi(n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n}\sqrt{h(d)} e_d$$.

Then we have:

$$ \left < \phi(a),\phi(b) \right > = \frac{\gcd(a,b)^2}{ab}=:k(a,b)$$

The vectors $\phi(a_i)$ are linearly independent for each finite set $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ of natural numbers, since

$$\det(G_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{h(a_i)}{a_i^2} $$
is not zero, where $G_n$ denotes the Gram matrix.

Define:

$$\hat{\phi}(n) := \sum_{d|n} \phi(d) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n} \sigma(\frac{n}{d})\sqrt{h(d)} e_d$$

For a prime $p$ define:

$$\zeta(p) := \sum_{l=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p^l} \phi(p^l)$$

The "coordinates" of $\zeta(p)$ in terms of the standard basis are:

$$\zeta(p) := \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p^2}}e_1+\sum_{l=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p^l\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{p^2}}} e_{p^l}$$

An odd perfect number $n$, satisfies:

$$\left < \hat{\phi}(n),\zeta(2) \right> = \frac{8}{3}$$

It was pointed to me, that if this "geometric approach" should work, then it has to avoid the even perfect numbers and the spoofs:

I checked a [few numbers](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1Ul2PmzAQfM-vsFSdtEsJ4LTJkUo83fup7yitSOxcLJyFGnBP9-tr8xFCdPWbd3ZmZ7Qr5JmVJRThEX-smHtGtp0h9nYSfTEINjFAgQEcEVcr4dp_XhRQ-Lrst_LUVgZy1vwxLVwuIBBjIGTqzOhJZFnCpG4kS9i5MkwwRcwU9CaBh69fOR5GbUekpXDTXSG_VvKougYoFhgI52lWEcqqpjIO60V6FccZTWY8ST7R86hwEf4r41VqLzGSfYos48Pnk9jckXzZZ5ybtGYZyw-3v59W3kef5KdXl46gVdOCH14iPqCRfG8lCQBal2uOQZ4cli1faqPIsctlWeuoqGvPvEdeyE27Fq1R76D1XLe-PiVzx6Gcz967Wnq_m_2XuOO8UKTIStNIwMDSDe16tL8MvnatEVXmCv62ZgUXuO_q07ueB2Ty390j4xL6hmFnHx-yLaBeLN5avwUeu9k8rn9tcFiID6Qf73Beh7XTSMesg0AHo_9BY1zN8gys9Re48srklfNduEnD7_tdyPfpNt1un3c83R-GIcOmKBwsbzASVfu7NpXoTi3cLpgnHDEiwDCNv0UJ_gMDaPyN&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), and I would be surprised if any other number $n$ satisifies the above equality $=8/3$.

My question is, if it is possible to check this on a computer for more even perfect numbers, or give a proof, that they do not satisify the equality above, or to check for larger spoof numbers on a computer.

Thanks for your help.